# Is it possible to change the icon of a MS-DOS bat file?

Tags: batch

I have a MS-DOS bat file that I have written.

However, I am wondering is it possible to change the icon to something different?

Comment: For just that one batch file or all batch files?

Answer (score 10):

The icon is determined by the command line extension, so no.

What you can do is create a *shortcut* to this application (right-click on the file in explorer and activate "Create Shortcut".

You can then set the icon on this shortcut to whatever you like.

Answer (score 4):

One option you have is to create a shortcut to the bat and then set an icon for the shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

There are tehnically two options here that change the icon of the source file, but you would either need to wrap the batch file with an SFX archive, or use [Bat To Exe Converter](http://www.f2ko.de/en/b2e.php). I personally use Bat To Exe Converter, because it allows you to set things like the icon, as well as version information and even personal favorites such as invisible launch and obfuscation. You can also use either [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/) or [Resource Editor](http://melander.dk/reseditor/) to add things that Bat To Exe Converter can't add during the building process. You can also use Resource Hacker on *some* projects to make changes after building in case you lose the source batch. The resource containing the script is usually under RCData-> B. Hope this helps...

Comment: Just to note, that Sophos now flags any .exe that was created with Bat to Exe Converter as a threat and deletes it.